# Remember URL parameters in django-tables2 with django-filter

Tags: python, django, django-filter, django-tables2

This is my view:

```
class FilteredReclamationListView(FilterView, SingleTableView):
    table_class = ReclamationTable
    model = ReclamationMainModel
    template_name = 'reclamation_table/index.html'
    filterset_class = ReclamationFilter
    table_pagination = {
    'per_page': 50
    }
    def get_table_data(self):
        return self.object_list
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.filter(archive=False).order_by('-id')
```

Is it possible to remember the URL parameter in this case? How?

I would like to have a situation that the user goes to another view and when he is back he will see his last query/filter. I read about sessions and `request.GET.urlencode()`, but I can't apply that in my view.

Comment: Hi @Aule, please elaborate, it is not clear what you want to achieve

Comment: Hello. Ok I will try.
When user is in FilteredReclamationListView view he can make some filter. The parameters of filter is in url ex. http://127.0.0.1:8000/?id=1&group=1 but when user go to another view and go back to FilteredReclamationListView view the parameter like id=1&group=1 are not remember. I would like to remember this  and when user go back to view he will go back to http://127.0.0.1:8000/?id=1&group=1 not http://127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: I gave you an answer. Use the session to store it

Answer (score 2):

I found a soluton to my problem. My first view looks like:

```
class FilteredReclamationListView(FilterView, SingleTableView):
    table_class = ReclamationTable
    model = ReclamationMainModel
    template_name = 'reclamation_table/index.html'
    filterset_class = ReclamationFilter
    table_pagination = {
        'per_page': 50
    }

    def get_table_data(self):
        return self.object_list

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.request.session['urltoremember'] = self.request.get_full_path()
        return self.model.objects.filter(archive=False).order_by('-id')
```

And in the second view I make this:

```
class ReclamationDetailView(DetailView):
    model = ReclamationMainModel
    context_object_name = 'reclamation_data'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ReclamationDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['filter'] = self.request.session['urltoremember']
        return context
```

In the template I change the link to go back to FilteredReclamationListView to `{{ filter }}`:

```
a href="{{ filter }}" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" id="menu-toggle">back</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Aule, you could store the filter on the session.

```
request.session['filter'] = myFilter
```

Comment: OK thank you very much but can you told me how to use session in my code?

Comment: try on the get_queryset. use self.request.session['filter']... let me know if that works....

Comment: Ok I trying to add self.request.session['filter'] to def get_queryset(self). I always have some error  and I dont understand what should I write and how should it look like. I also read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering and other topic on stackoverflow with session but I do not understand how it work.

Comment: try adding it to     def get_context_data(self, **kwargs) then